# Facebook Page Plugin Just Not Working

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I am trying to implement the facebook page plugin into my website but it is just not working it just shows some simple text with my webpage name like a normal anchor link but nothing else. it also say file://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js is not found in developer tools but when I punch in that address into the web browser it does find the link. Please help this is driving me up the wall

Comment: Please: post code you tried. And are you ACTUALLY trying on a website, or on a file? (tag me to get my attention @danispringer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the facebook page plugin doesn't work the same as the twitter plugin. With twitter you can test your site locally and if you are connected to the internet the plugin will still pull through the data not so with the facebook plugin. How I managed to get it to work was by uploading my file onto my live server and it worked. I have no idea why this happens. Thanks for your help Dani